# rust_decimal: format without trailing zeroes

Tags: rust, format, decimal

`Display` doesn't quite work:

```rust
let d = Decimal::from_str("132.10000")?;
println!("{}", d); // prints 132.10000
```

Format specifiers don't work either:

```rust
let d = Decimal::from_str("132")?;
println!("{:.2}", d); // prints 132.00
```

Is there anything similar to Java's [`DecimalFormat("0")`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), or .NET's [`ToString("0.##")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)?

Comment: _"Format specifiers don't work either"_ -- But then you show them working. It prints `132.00` because you specified `.2`.  If you specify `.0` then you won't get any trailing zeroes. I tested that and it works. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: To be clear, you want `1.0 => 1`, `1.1 => 1.1`, `1.11 => 1.11`, `1.111 => 1.11` right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.normalize()`](https://docs.rs/rust_decimal/latest/rust_decimal/struct.Decimal.html#method.normalize) (or [`.normalize_assign()`](https://docs.rs/rust_decimal/latest/rust_decimal/struct.Decimal.html#method.normalize_assign)):

> Strips any trailing zero’s from a `Decimal` and converts -0 to 0.

and then print the result.